# Erro ao encontrar o centro de um objeto OpenCV Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, visão-computacional

Olá, estou estudando opencv para utilizar em um drone e enquanto eu implementava um código de um tutorial que detectava objetos e desenhava um circulo no centro do mesmo, e para isso deve-se pegar a metade das dimensões `x+w` e `y+h` só que o problema é que quando eu vou fazer `x+w/2` e `y+h/2`aparece o seguinte erro: `integer argument expected, got float`. HELP ME!!

Código:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.cv2.VideoCapture(0)
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    rangomax = np.array([50,255,50])
    rangomin = np.array([0, 51, 0])
    mascara = cv2.cv2.inRange(frame, rangomin, rangomax)
    opening = cv2.cv2.morphologyEx(mascara, cv2.cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.cv2.boundingRect(opening)
    cv2.cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0), 3)
    cv2.cv2.circle(frame,(x+w/2, y+h/2), 5,(0,0,255), -1)
    cv2.cv2.imshow('video', frame)
    k = cv2.cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
cap.release()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ele espera um valor int
tente usar o construtor int() para fazer o que seria um *cast*

[Python](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html):

```
cv.Circle(img, center, radius, color, thickness=1, lineType=8, shift=0) → None
```

então seria

```
cv2.cv2.circle(frame,(int(x+w/2), int(y+h/2)), 5,(0,0,255), -1)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado :)